# Multiple CI application in a sub-domain

Tags: apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am new to Apache environment. Preferably I do not want .htaccess file, but I think I have not choice. My application runs without problem in my notebook which is windows environment using WAMPSERVER. But when I deploy to hosting server which uses Apache, I face some problems. I am not sure the following structure is correct for CodeIgniter application. Following is the directory structure in hosting server...

```
httodocs/
/survey
    /admin
          /config           <-- $route['default_controller'] = "admin";
          /controllers
          /models
          /views
          /...
    /statistic
          /config           <-- $route['default_controller'] = "statistic";
          /controllers
          /models
          /views
          /...
    /mySurvey
          /config           <-- $route['default_controller'] = "mySurvey";
          /controllers
          /models
          /views
          /...
    /css
    /images
    /scripts
    /system
    /...
/index.php                  <-- $application_folder = 'mySurvey'; 
/admin.php                  <-- $application_folder = 'admin';
/Statistic.php              <-- $application_folder = 'statistic';
```

What I did was just duplicate the Application folder and rename to admin, statistic and mySurvey respectively, I set the default controller as stated above.

all application `base_url() = 'http://survey.myhost.com'` which is a sub domain under myhost.com

The root index.php is actually CI application environment which allow user to go to mySurvey application by default, when they enter "http://survey.myhost.com".

From the first page on, when I access http://survey.myhost.com/index.php/mySurvey/index/0
I got error:

```
`The specified CGI application misbehaved by not retruning a complete set of HTTP headers.`
```

The same message shows when I access `http://survey.myhost.com/admin.php/admin/login` or `http://survey.myhost.com/statistic.php?statistic/chart/1` (note that I also do use query string for my application)

Obviously, these have to do with the route. I do not have any .htaccess file at the server because WAMP does not need it, Appreciate if anyone can advice where can I put the .htaccess file and what is the correct mod-rewrite for the structure above and is this structure appropriate.

Regards,

KK Gian

Answer (score 0):

```
root
  /subs
    /survey (survey.domain.tld)
      /application (CI application folder)  
        /config
        /models
        ...
      index.php (CI index.php file)
    /statistics
      /application (CI application folder)
        /config
        /models
        ...
      index.php (CI index.php file)
    /mySurvey
      /application (CI application folder) 
        /config
        /models
        ...
      index.php (CI index.php file)

  /system (CI system folder)
```

in every `index.php` (subs/survey/index.php, subs/mysurvey/idnex.php, subs/statistics/index.php) you will link at `root/system/` folder so

```
$system_path = '../../system';
```

now you can easily go to survey.myhost.com, statistics.myhost.com etc. remove index.php, admin.php strings from url (`$config['index_page'] = '';`)

hope I got what you want

> sorry for my english

Comment: Dear @MireSVK, Thank you for your reply and suggestion. Your suggestion is to put each application into different sub domain. That is not what I want. Base on my original idea, I only need 1 sub domain which is survey.myhost.com. The Statistic and Admin 'module' are inside it. I hope you understand my problems.

Comment: I am sorry, I will look for some solution later (today). I will post it here in case of good solution. Now, try to insert line `header('Content-type: text/html');` somewhere into index.php, staticists.php and admin.php. Look for some missing header data in HTTP header (response) via FireBug (FF) or DragonFly (Opera)